# P50 much higher than weighted average

Tags: statistics

I have a few hundreds of results of the lead time for order/s delivery from its shipment. When I analyze these results I see that in some cases, the P$50$ value is much higher than the weighted Average result...
I find this very odd. Does this mean that the 50%  of the results below the P50  value is probably very small and far from the mean?

Also, what else can this tell me about my results?

Details on the results : average = $5.5$ days, P$50$ = $17$ days.
A valid result could be anything from $0$ up to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A left-skewed distribution (thin tail to the left) will tend
to give random samples with mean smaller than median. It takes only relatively few small observations to 'pull'
the mean below the median, so the difference need not
be great.

For example:

```
set.seed(1015)
x = 100*rbeta(100, 20, 1)
summary(x)
    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   80.18   93.35   96.71   95.02   98.34   99.99 

hist(x, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

In this particular example, the *population* median is 96.59 and
the population mean is 95.24.

```
qbeta(.5, 20, 1)*100
[1] 96.59363
2000/21
[1] 95.2381
```

Comment: Thanks Bruce, makes sense.